# Java: Split a non singular java.awt.geom.area into distinct, singular areas

Tags: java, swing, geometry, awt

Edit for the Googlers: I figured it out. I can't write explicit code but the steps are:

- Create the big, non singular area (result of a substract or intersect for example)
- if isSingular, do normal code
- else:

  - create an ArrayList, to place all the sections into
  - Create a PathIterator (iter)
  - Create a Path2D (path)
  - while not iter isDone (use iter.next() at end of loop)

    - create double[2] (coordsArray) array to place coords
    - create int (coords), the currentSegment or iter. coordsArray is always the arg
    - ifs or switch,

      - when the type of iter is SEG_MOVETO, move path to the coords (x,y)stored in your coordsArray index 0, 1.
      - when the type is SEG_CLOSE, create new Area, with path as arg, add to section array, then path.reset
      - Else, your path must lineTo the coords store in the coordsArray, instead of moveTo

You will end up with a new array resulting of those small areas. Iter through this array and do your //normalCode on it as if they had been singular arrays in the first place

// End of result edit //

// Initial question

I get small areas from the result of intersect() on a bigger one serving as boundaries. It crops the small areas. Sometimes it can lead to the area being split in 2 or more sections that don't touch each other, but counting as 1 area for which isSingular() returns false.

I need to get the individual dimensions of the bounds2D() of those distinct sections, so I need to split them into different areas. I thought I could do it with PathIterator, but I can't seem to find a way to distinguish the sections. I already discard areas that are isEmpty(), so if I have "holes" in an area, it's fine it it creates separate hole areas, they will be discarded afterwards.

Is it at all possible?

Thanks!

Edit: clarification

I create small rectangular areas. Then I intersect() with a bigger, irregular polygon being the boundaries of those smaller areas. Because of the irregular shape of the boundaries, my rectangle can end up being cropped in irregular polygons too. That's fine. But sometimes, it could cut it in separate halves that don't touch in any point. Then, those 2 halves count as only 1 areas. I don't want that. I want to take this area made of 2 halves, and make 2 distinct areas with them.

Basically, when []__[]  == bigArea, I want to do [],  [] = smallArea1, smallArea2.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What specifically are you struggling with after splitting areas?

Comment: Added clarifications in the main post. Problem is I can't split those areas in the first place. I get 1 single area object, made of multiple sections that don't touch, because of substractions (intersect). I want each section to become it's own area.

Comment: There's no easy answer to this. You might want to check out openCV to see if that might help you

Comment: What's the reason for tagging this JavaFX? Swing and JavaFX are different apis.

Comment: Here's what you (and I) have been looking for so long: [javagl.Geom.Shapes#computeSubShapes](https://github.com/javagl/Geom/blob/master/src/main/java/de/javagl/geom/Shapes.java#L429).